# Apache storm + Kafka Spout

Tags: apache-storm

got a Storm 2.6.0 with Kafka spout (setting 32 parallelismHint)

and sometimes I'm getting

```
Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error in commit: The group id does not exist.
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:413) ~[storm-client-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error in commit: The group id does not exist.
.....
2024-03-19 00:51:00.669 o.a.s.u.Utils Thread-288-channel-kafka-executor[55, 55] [ERROR] Halting process: Worker died
java.lang.RuntimeException: Halting process: Worker died
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.exitProcess(Utils.java:519) [storm-client-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$3.run(Utils.java:874) [storm-client-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.apache.storm.executor.error.ReportErrorAndDie.uncaughtException(ReportErrorAndDie.java:41) [storm-client-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:2901) [?:?]
```

he recover himself ...
Is this error normal ?